# SQL Lite in Android studio wont insert attributes

Tags: android, sql, database, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

Ive been having this problem for a while now. For some reason it adds it to the database but it gives this error and crashes my program.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.example.munaj.feedmeg.DataBaseHelper.insertRow(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

There's a lot of random fillers but ive located where my errors are.

[image]

This is my database file

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; // used for logging database version

//Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_START_TIME = "sTime";
public static final String KEY_FINISH_TIME = "fTime";
public static final String KEY_LOC = "loc";
public static final String KEY_ROOM = "room";
public static final String KEY_DES = "des";


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TASK, KEY_DATE,KEY_START_TIME, KEY_FINISH_TIME, KEY_LOC, KEY_ROOM, KEY_DES};

public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
public static final int COL_DATE = 2;
public static final int COL_FTIME = 3;

//Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbToDo";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainToDo";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TASK + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_START_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_FINISH_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_LOC + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_DES + " TEXT NOT NULL"
        + ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
//Open the database connection
public DataBaseHelper open(){
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
//Close the database connection
public void close(){
    myDBHelper.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String task, String date,String startTime, String finishTime, String loc, String room, String des){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE,date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_START_TIME,startTime);
    initialValues.put(KEY_FINISH_TIME,finishTime);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LOC,loc);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ROOM,room);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DES,des);


    //Insert the data into the database
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
//Delete a row from the database, by rowId(primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId){
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll(){
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int)rowId));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}
//Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows(){
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
//Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getRow(long rowId){
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,where,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
//Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date,String startTime, String finishTime, String loc, String room, String des){
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TASK,task);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    newValues.put(KEY_START_TIME,startTime);
    newValues.put(KEY_FINISH_TIME,finishTime);
    newValues.put(KEY_LOC, loc);
    newValues.put(KEY_ROOM, room);
    newValues.put(KEY_DES, des);

    //Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,newValues,where,null) != 0;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db){
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading Application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");
        //Destroy old database;
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  DATABASE_TABLE);
        //Recreates new database:
        onCreate(_db);

    }
}
}
```

Main Program

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DataBaseHelper myDb;
//Time zone
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
String etTasks;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etTasks = "KKKK";
    openDB();
    populateListView();
    //listViewItemClick();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
//Opening the database
public void openDB(){
    myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    myDb.open();
}
public void insertMe(String a, String s, String d, String f, String g, String h, String j){
(****ERROR HERE****)myDb.insertRow(a,s,d,f,g,h,j);
    populateListView();
}
public void populateListView(){
    //Cursor went into data base and got all the rows
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "PARTYYY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }
    //then places them into these arrays
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{
            DataBaseHelper.KEY_START_TIME,DataBaseHelper.KEY_TASK,DataBaseHelper.KEY_LOC, DataBaseHelper.KEY_FINISH_TIME, DataBaseHelper.KEY_DATE, DataBaseHelper.KEY_ROOM, DataBaseHelper.KEY_DES};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {
            R.id.sTime, R.id.food,R.id.loc, R.id.fTime, R.id.date, R.id.room, R.id.des};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_layout, cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}

private void updateTask(long id){
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(id);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String task = etTasks;
        String fTime = "2pm";
        String sTime = "12pm";
        String loc = "UC";
        String room = "103";
        String des = "Fun Event Great Time";
        today.setToNow();
        String date = today.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        myDb.updateRow(id,task,date,sTime,fTime,loc,room,des);
    }
    cursor.close();
}

private void listViewItemClick(){
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long id) {
            updateTask(id);
            populateListView();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F44336")));
        return true;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.action_login)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Clubs.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Clubs Program

```
public class Clubs extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
EditText clubName;
TextView nameError;
TextView dateError;
TextView locError;
TextView startError;
TextView endError;
TextView foodError;
TextView desError;

ImageButton add;
ImageButton date;
ImageButton loc;
ImageButton sTime;
ImageButton eTime;
ImageButton foodType;

Button des;

int year, month, day;
int hour, minute, eHour, eMinute;
String name, description = "", location = "---", food = "---";
ArrayList<Library> library = new ArrayList<>();

Library lib = new Library();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clubs);
    des = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDes);
    clubName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    nameError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNameError);
    dateError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDError);
    locError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLError);
    startError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSError);
    endError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFinError);
    foodError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFoError);
    desError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDesError);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    date = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    loc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLoc);
    sTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSTime);
    eTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnETime);
    foodType = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFood);

    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dDate =  new DatePickerDialog(Clubs.this, dpickerListner, year, month, day);
            dDate.show();
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListner
                    = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year_x, int month_x, int day_x){
                    year = year_x;
                    month = month_x + 1;
                    day = day_x;

                    Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, year + "/" + month + "/" + day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
        }
    });

    loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Clubs.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Building");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.description_dialog);
            dialog.show();

            Button done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
            final EditText dDialog = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    location = dDialog.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Saved " + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    sTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimePickerDialog tTime = new TimePickerDialog(Clubs.this, sTimePickerListner, hour, minute,false);
            tTime.show();
        }
    });

    eTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimePickerDialog tTime = new TimePickerDialog(Clubs.this, eTimePickerListner, eHour, eMinute,false);
            tTime.show();
        }
    });

    foodType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Clubs.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Food");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.food_spinner_dialog);
            dialog.show();

            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_food);
            final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Clubs.this, R.array.Food, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(Clubs.this);

            Button done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSpDoneFood);
            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    food = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if (food.equals("---")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Pick a Food item!, " + food, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Saved, " + food, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    des.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Clubs.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Description of Event");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.description_dialog);
            dialog.show();

            Button done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
            final EditText dDialog = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    description = dDialog.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Food product = new Food(clubName.getText().toString());

            if (clubName.getText().toString().equals("") || year == 0 || month == 0 || day == 0 || hour == 0 || eHour == 0 || location.equals("---") || description.equals("")) {
             Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Input Error, check all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else{
            lib.addItem(year, month, day, location, hour, minute, eHour, eMinute, food, description);
            Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "PARTYYY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String dateBooked = (month + " " + day + ", " + year);
                String startTime = (hour + ":" + minute);
                String finishTime = (eHour + ":" + eMinute);
                int room = 222;
                String locc = "UC";
                String dess = "LOOL";
                String x = clubName.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Clubs.this,clubName.getText().toString()  + "... " + startTime + " .." + finishTime + ".. loc: " + location + "..food: " +food + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

(****ERROR HERE****)new MainActivity().insertMe("dude","a","a","a","a","a","a");**



                Intent intent = new Intent(Clubs.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            if (clubName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                nameError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                nameError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (year == 0 || month == 0 || day == 0) {
                dateError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                dateError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (hour == 0) {
                startError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                startError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (eHour == 0) {
                endError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                endError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (location.equals("---")) {
                locError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                locError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (description.equals("")) {
                desError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                desError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}
//*****************************************************DATE PICKER***************************************************************
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListner
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year_x, int month_x, int day_x){
        year = year_x;
        month = month_x + 1;
        day = day_x;

        Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
//*****************************************************TIME PICKER***************************************************************

protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener sTimePickerListner =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hour_x, int minute_x){
                hour = hour_x;
                minute = minute_x;
                Toast.makeText(Clubs.this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener eTimePickerListner =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hour_x, int minute_x){
                eHour = hour_x;
                eMinute = minute_x;
                Toast.makeText(Clubs.this,"Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_clubs, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.action_sign_out)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Clubs.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView myText = (TextView) view;
    food = (String) myText.getText();
    if (!food.equals("---")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Food:  " + food, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `insertMe` method from Activity which is not running causing  `NullPointerException`.

To get it work create `DataBaseHelper` class object in `Clubs` Activity and then call `insertRow` method.

```
DataBaseHelper myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
myDb.insertRow();
```

Comment: The clubs program doesnt use the database at all. It sends the values needed to be added to the main. In the main i have what you wrote but it gives me almost the same error.

Comment: @MunajSyed: Problem is MainActivity is not running and you are calling `insertMe` from it which is not right way to share data between Activity. if want to insert data in Main then start Clubs Activity using startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult to get data back

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. Is there a better way where i can store the data from the clubs program and display it in the mainactivity. Thats all want to do for this program.

Comment: @MunajSyed: Yes, using `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`. see following example :http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: Thank you so much! you have helped me fixed the problem!!!!!